# Prebuilt nginx default options (configuration)?

Tags: nginx

What are the config options of a pre built nginx ?

Specifically are the following on or off?

> --with-threads --with-file-aio --with-ipv6 -with-http_ssl_module --with-http_v2_module

when I built on my ubuntu I gave the command :

```
./configure --prefix=/data/apps/ngx/n1_12_0 --with-debug --with-threads --with-file-aio --with-ipv6 --with-http_ssl_module --with-http_v2_module
```

Notably not used:
--with-http_realip_module

What is the configure command in the pre-built Ubuntu package ? I guess its the same options for all platforms?

Comment: And if any of you are using nginx with threads in prod please comment here or is there a web server forum, better suited than super user to discuss at?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can use

```
nginx -V
```

To see the options that it was built with.

If you install from an pre built version it keeps a copy of the old executable. Though need to back up conf folder

```
mkdir $nginxBackUp/confs2017may30 
mv /etc/nginx/* $nginxBackUp/confs2017may30/
```

So to have two versions of nginx, I made a copy of the conf, new directories for logs, pid, etc.
Move the nginx executable. And when you run the other version of nginx give it alternate paths for --prefix, --conf,  --http-log-path, --error-log-path=, --lock-path, --pid-path,  --modules-path ...

This way can keep old and new nginx ready and can switch by stopping current and switching to other.